# IS there a better way of writing the file content to email attachment in power automate?

Tags: power-automate

I had an requirement wherein I had to configure `"send email"` action in Power automate that will send an excel file as an attachment as soon as the file is generated. The work flow works fine. However, while testing I found that the received excel attachment  had few rows missing. So, I added a `"delay"` action between a `"Apply to each"` and `"send email"`. The delay is configured with `50 sec`. So, in the testing environment the data is smaller in size, so it is working. But in real time the data could be of 1000 rows and the excel file generation is not static. the number of files may vary depending upon the business requirements. i.e. if 4 excel file generated then 4 emails would be sent and the flow is doing it.

So, is there other reliable solution that I can implement to address any number of file and data?

Comment: How is it supposed to know that there may be four files today and then three tomorrow? It has to know when to stop waiting for more files.

Comment: Where is the file? SharePoint/OneDrive? Some ideas. Check when Created date <> Modified date? Or create the file in a folder, and after the creation has finished, move the file to new watched folder location. What is generating the file?

Comment: its in one drive. There is an API in http action that is getting data, and then dumping them into a excel file

Comment: Can you answer my question?

Comment: Agreeing with @Skin the flow has to use a different trigger. If you can bundle the flows in a solution, you can define the email sending flow as a child flow. You can then call it after the main flow fetching the file is finished.